# Should I call close() on URLLoader after an error?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

When using URLLoader two types of errors are possible: exceptions which can be catched in try {} block and error events which can be handled by handler functions.

Should I call close() on my URLLoader object after exception/error event occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question - I gave this code a try and didn't get the error you would expect (stream error):

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

urlLoader.load( new URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com/test.jpg") );
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error);

function error(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    // Don't get the stream error, meaning the stream is still open.
    urlLoader.close();
}
```

I then thought to myself that maybe it just closes half a second later, so I attached a `setTimeout()` to the close call. Still didn't get the error.

```
function error(e:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        // Still no error.
        trace("Test.");
        urlLoader.close();

    }, 3000);
}
```

To double check, I ran this to make sure we still actually get that error:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.close(); // Error: Error #2029: This URLStream object does not have
                   // a stream opened.
```

So, it *seems* as though you actually do need to `.close()` a stream if there is an error. How weird. That said, I am still in disbelief, so I welcome any evidence against this.

Comment: Is it possible that `close()` is only intended for stopping a download in progress, and not a required "cleanup" method? The [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#close()) sort of imply this, but are terse and also state that it throws the error if there's "no URL being streamed".